# Spring Boot message.properties Question: How to send value to the fragment?

Tags: java, spring-boot, properties, thymeleaf

I have a problem about sending the value coming from message.properties file to the thymeleaf fragment page.
After I defined the value in message.properites file named as "brand.name" , I'd like to send it to that page but I couldn't handle with it.

Even if I can use `column_link('name',[[#{brand.name}]],'none')"` or `column_link('name',#{brand.name},'none')"`, I cannot show the name in fragment.

How can I do that?

Here is my message_en.properties file shown below.

```
...
brand.name = Brand Name:
...
```

Here is my HTML page shown below.

```
...
<th th:replace="fragments :: column_link('name','Brand Name','none')" />
...
```

Here is my fragment page shown below.

```
<th th:fragment="column_link(fieldName, columnLabel, removeTag)" th:remove="${removeTag}">
    
        <a class="text-white"
            th:href="@{${moduleURL} + '/page/' + ${currentPage} + '?sortField=' + ${fieldName}  +'&sortDir=' + ${sortField != fieldName ? sortDir : reverseSortDir} + ${keyword != null ? '&keyword=' + keyword : ''}">
            [[${columnLabel}]]
        </a>                                
        <span th:if="${sortField == fieldName}"
            th:class="${sortDir == 'asc' ? 'fas fa-sort-up' : 'fas fa-sort-down'}" ></span> 
                            
</th>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to pass a property in like this:

```
<th th:replace="fragments :: column_link('name',#{brand.name},'none')" />
```